# use a for-loop to iterate down a row in google apps script/collecting multiple pieces of data / outputing based on nested if statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-sheets

```
function myFunction() {

    var app=SpreadsheetApp;
    var sheet= app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow= sheet.getLastRow();

    for(i=4;i<=lastRow;i++) {

        var compType=sheet.getRange(i, 13).getValues();
        var jobTitle=sheet.getRange(i,2).getValues();
        var validchoice=sheet.getRange(i,13-1);

        if (carType==="Small Hybrid") { 

            if (gasmileage.match(/(thirty mile per gallon|thirty one mile per gallon|thirty two mile per gallon|thirty three mile per gallon|thirty four mile per gallon|thirty five mile per gallon|thirty six mile per gallon)/i)) {

                validchoice.setValue("Y");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your range data into an Array by calling `getValues()`. This will make your script run [much faster](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations). Make sure you also define `carType` and `gasmileage` as they're both used in your function, but have not been defined.

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Getting the Active Sheet can cause unexpected results
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B:M");
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); //Column B = column 2. Column M = column 13. (Determine column numbers by writing =COLUMN() into the columns)
  var validChoiceColumnNumber = 12; //Column L = column 12
  for(var i=3; i<data.length; i++) { //Arrays, unlike ranges, are 0-indexed so we subtract 1
    var row = data[i]; //When i==3, this displays the data for row 4 (since arrays are 0-indexed)
    var compType = row[12]; //Column M = 13, but since arrays are 0-indexed, subtract 1
    var jobTitle = row[1]; //Column B
    var validchoice = row[validChoiceColumnNumber-1];
    var carType = undefined; //YOU DIDN'T DEFINE THIS VALUE
    var gasmileage = undefined; //YOU DIDN'T DEFINE THIS VALUE
    if (carType==="Small Hybrid") { //See above. You didn't define carType
      if (gasmileage.match(/(thirty mile per gallon|thirty one mile per gallon|thirty two mile per gallon|thirty three mile per gallon|thirty four mile per gallon|thirty five mile per gallon|thirty six mile per gallon)/i)) {
        dataRange.getCell(i+1, validChoiceColumnNumber).setValue("Y"); //getCell() requires we switch back to 1-indexed – https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcellrow-column
      }
    }
  }
}
```